# How to fix col problem with opera browser?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, opera

I'm working with Bootstrap and noticed that the website is not working properly on Opera Browser. It is showing my columns half size to the left side of the page.

```css
.services-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.623);
  box-shadow:25 25 25 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 25);
}
.services-info-span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.623);
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
  box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 25)
}
```

```html
<section id="services">
  <div class="container-fluid services">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3 services-info"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3 services-info-span"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3 services-info"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3 services-info-span"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I expect to have column with the right size on Opera.

Comment: What version of Opera? What OS?

Comment: iin your `<div class="col-md-3 col-3 services-info"></div>` tag `col-md-3` redundant since you are already using `col-3`, anyway your question is not fully clear, can you please attach a screenshot of your view